# In Perforce P4V, how to I search for changelists with files in particular folders?

Tags: perforce

In Perforce P4V, I'd like to do a search for all changelists that have files from a particular set of folders, that all have "index" in the folder name, and also have another folder at the beginning.  For instance, I want to see all changelists against any files in folders like these:

\depot\abc\def\table\index*.*

\depot\abc\ghi\table\index*.*

so basically any folders that match the pattern

\depot\abc\...\table\index*.*

But this doesn't appear to work.  Any ideas?  Also is there any detailed information on using perforce wildcards online?  I was not able to find a whole lot.  This must be something that lots of people need to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use both P4V on Windows and I use the 'p4' command line client on Linux.  What you're asking for actually uses two Perforce client commands:

- p4 changes
- p4 describe

On P4V specifically, this is done under the menu option View->Submitted Changelists (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>).  This should open a tab for searching.  In the Folder/file input field, type a path expression, like this:

```
//depot/main/app/python/SiteControl/.../*.html
```

When I run this against my depot, I get a list of changelists.  When I click on a changelist, it expands to a list of files.  The files matching the pattern *.html are in normal font weight/color, and the non-matching files are "greyed out".  Does that make sense?

Similarly, and more specific to your question/usage, you can use a wildcard to say "all files with index at the beginning of their name", as so:

```
//depot/main/app/python/SiteControl/.../index.*
```

---

Now just to compare, run it again but remove the "/index.*" from the path expression.  Now what you'll see are **all** of the submitted changelists under the depot path - not just the ones that contain html files.  Additionally, all files will appear in normal font weight/color.

HTH,

-aj

Comment: Thanks!  It turns out that I was running an older version of P4V. Now that I've got the latest version, everything works as you described.